# c# Excel Application.EnableEvents

Tags: c#, excel

I have to create an Excel-COM-Add-In, that validate some values of several cells. Normally this requirement is easy to realise, but in the actual case there is installed another COM-Add-IN, which set the flag for the "Application.EnableEvents" to false. The result is, that no event will be fired at runtime. My question is: "How can I recognize if the flag was set by the COM-ADD-In at runtime?" or "Is it possible to create an eventhandler to monitoring this flag?"

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to handle all cases of bad behavior by other addins.
You could check at workbook.open time what enableevents is set to ...